# Stored Procedure not reading from variable in IF-ELSE statement

Tags: plsql, oracle19c

I started writing this stored procedure and I faced some issues when I try to pass a variable in my conditional statement.

I can use the parameter **BANKN** which works fine, but when never I passed the declared variable **AC_t** somehow the PL/SQL ignores it.

Any idea please what I'm missing here?

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE TTEST1 (
  CR IN VARCHAR2,
  BANKN IN VARCHAR2,
  P_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
AS
  G_AC CHAR(10);
  AC_t Billing.Account %Type;

BEGIN
  IF BANKN = 'WLNV' AND AC_t = 'Private'
  THEN
    IF CR IN (
      'EUR',
      'CZK',
      'USD'
    )
    THEN
      OPEN P_CURSOR
        FOR
        SELECT G_AC AS GL_ACC,
               Billing.Account AS ACC_Type
        INTO 
               G_AC,
               AC_t
        FROM Billing
             INNER JOIN invoice ON Billing.ACC_NO = invoice.ACC_NO;
    END IF ;
  END IF ;
END;
```

My aim here is to expand this code by using AC_t value from Billing.ACCount and retrieve what ever data that can be 'Private' or 'Public'.

To do this, I need to use case or IF statement, however when I use
Billing.ACCount, I got an error "not allowed in this context", for this reason I use synonym AC_t but this don't read values from Billing table unless I use it in WHERE clause.

| ACC_NO | Account |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Private |
| 2 | Public |

Extended code:

```
IF BANKN = 'WLNV' AND AC_t = 'Private'
THEN
...
...
ELSIF IF BANKN = 'WLNV' AND AC_t = 'Public'
THEN 
....
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `SELECT ... INTO` with a cursor and you need to declare a value for the `ac_t` variable (but since it is a column in the table you may want a `WHERE` clause in the cursor). Like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE TTEST1 (
  p_CR     IN  VARCHAR2,
  p_BANKN  IN  VARCHAR2,
  P_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) 
AS
BEGIN
  IF  p_BANKN = 'WLNV'
  AND p_CR IN ( 'EUR', 'CZK', 'USD' )
  THEN
    OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
      SELECT G_AC AS GL_ACC,
             b.account AS ACC_Type
      FROM   Billing b
             INNER JOIN invoice i
             ON b.ACC_NO = i.ACC_NO
      WHERE  b.account = 'Private';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Which, if you have the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE invoice (acc_no, g_AC) AS
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE billing (acc_no, account) AS
SELECT 1, 'Private' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can call the procedure and print the contents of the cursor using:

```sql
DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_g_ac INVOICE.G_AC%TYPE;
  v_ac_t BILLING.ACCOUNT%TYPE;
BEGIN
  ttest1('EUR', 'WLNV', cur);
  
  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO v_g_ac, v_ac_t;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_g_ac || ', ' || v_ac_t );
  END LOOP;
  
  CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 2, Private
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=86ca7cc590ee13445b0228477332e0ef)*

Comment: Thanks. I actually want to retrieve the value of AC_t from table in db then if its equal to what ever value I passed to it in ( if else statement ). In this code you have , you need to manually input the value whereas I want it from the databse.

Comment: @Joe You declared an `ac_t` PL/SQL variable and then never assigned a value to it before comparing it in the `IF` statement using `AC_t  = 'Private'` when that is never going to be true as `AC_t` was the default `NULL` value. You could use a `WHERE` filter in the query rather than trying a PL/SQL comparison but since you have not given any sample data and neither have you told us what your expected output is then we are left trying to guess what you do want..

Comment: @MT10. My aim is, instead of using  WHERE Billing.ACC_NO = 'Private' which will work, I want to use Billing.ACC_NO in the IF statement , but since it is not allowed to use  'IF Billing.ACC_NO = 'Private' ' to check if this value exist in Billing table, I used the synonym AC_t and assigned a value in the IF statement but it doesn't seem to be reading any value.